Unit-testing MapStruct with JPA repository injected (Spring, JUnit, Mockito)
I have:
Java Spring WEB app. Unit-testing MapStruct with JPA repository injected (JUnit, Mockito).
My problem:
I made my tests work, but I can't understand how they work and I have doubts whether it is a good practice in unit-testing.
Long detailed story:
I am writing unit-tests for the MapStruct class (ExchangeRateMapper, or rather ExchangeRateMapperImpl).
This mapper has injected dependency - JPA repository (CurrencyRepository).
This is simplified view of mapper:
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class ExchangeRateMapper {
    @Autowired
    private CurrencyRepository currencyRepository;

    // ...
}

I tried to write tests, mocking JPA repository.
That way it doesn't work:
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ExchangeRateMapperImpl.class})
public class ExchangeRateMapperTests {
    @Mock
    CurrencyRepository currencyRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    @Autowired
    ExchangeRateMapper exchangeRateMapper;

    // ...

    @Test
    void exchangeRateXMLOToExchangeRateDOTest() {
        Mockito.when(currencyRepository.findByCode("EUR")).thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(currencyEUR));
        Mockito.when(currencyRepository.findByCode("USD")).thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(currencyUSD));
        ExchangeRateDO result = exchangeRateMapper.exchangeRateXMLOToExchangeRateDO(exchangeRateXMLO);
        Assertions.assertEquals(exchangeRateDO, result);
    }
}

However, when I changed @Mock to @MockBean (org.mockito.Mock to org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean)
and remove @InjectMocks,
then it works:
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ExchangeRateMapperImpl.class})
public class ExchangeRateMapperTests {
    @MockBean
    CurrencyRepository currencyRepository;

    @Autowired
    ExchangeRateMapper exchangeRateMapper;

    // ...

    @Test
    void exchangeRateXMLOToExchangeRateDOTest() {
        Mockito.when(currencyRepository.findByCode("EUR")).thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(currencyEUR));
        Mockito.when(currencyRepository.findByCode("USD")).thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(currencyUSD));
        ExchangeRateDO result = exchangeRateMapper.exchangeRateXMLOToExchangeRateDO(exchangeRateXMLO);
        Assertions.assertEquals(exchangeRateDO, result);
    }
}

Can somebody explain, please, why it works only that strange way?
Is this approach acceptable or, if not, what would be better solution to test such mapper?
I expected tests to work with @Mock and @InjectMocks. I guess that problem is in ExchangeRateMapper being abstract class and CurrencyRepository being interface, withal me wanting dependencies be injected automatically within Spring context. Still, I don't get where exactly is problem.
UPDATE 07.05.2024:
Removed info about using @Inject from question, as it was my mistake, no need of it.

It isn't strange, you want spring to manage the injection, but in your test totally bypass Spring as you let plain Mockito control it. Using @MockBean and @Autowired lets Spring do the control again.

@m-deinum Oh, now it is more clear, thank you! I had wanted to ask more about not working without @Inject, but I have rebuilt project and tests are working with just @MockBean and @Autowired, so all behaves as in docs Annotation Interface @MockBean - When registered by type, any existing single bean of a matching type (including subclasses) in the context will be replaced by the mock. Thanks again for explanation.

You must not use SpringExtension and MockitoExtension at the same time. Pick one.
